# Open item in language version in which search result was returned

Tags: content-editor, buckets

Currently facing an issue where when you search bucketed items within Sitecore, in let us say Danish language, you get Danish results but clicking on that item opens an English version in new content editor tab.
Has anyone ever reported this to Sitecore and got a hotfix?
Or has anyone done any customization to fix this?

Comment: yes this a known bug, I had this bug on version 7.5 and the bug number was 404768

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Sitecore Climber its a known bug with the reference number 404768.

It was fixed in [8.2 Update 4 (rev. 170614)](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/82/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2082%20Update4/Release%20Notes).

> **Content Editor** - Searching in the content tree opens an item in the default language.